# Изменить параметры лога

Tags: sql, sql-server

Всем привет

Как изменить настройки лога транзакции?
Сейчас стоит шаг по 50, лимит 2 097 152
Размер 150 000

Я хочу сделать его без ограничений. Если Меняю в настройках ставлю "без ограничения" жму ок.

Все возвращается к тому же с чего начинал
шаг 50, лимит 2 097 152 размер 150000

Comment: Выдержка из [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-file-and-filegroup-options?view=sql-server-ver15): "_файл журнала, для которого задано неограниченное увеличение размера, имеет **максимальный размер 2 ТБ**_"